# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and 1-to-1. Show that for each borel $E$, $f(E)$ is borel

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and 1-to-1. Show that for each borel $E$, $f(E)$ is borel.

Since $f$ is continuous it is measurable. So if $M $ is borel, $f^{-1}(M)$ is borel too. However, we are not working with pre-images here. It is clear that $f (f^{-1} M) = M$ due to $f$ being 1-to-1 but I'm sure we can not characterize all borel sets of the domain by $f^{-1}(M)$.

I'm stuck here. Any help will be appreiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Each open set is a countable union of compact sets. It follows by the continuity of $f$ that if $U$ is open, then $f(U)$ is Borel. Let

$$\mathcal E =\{E:f(E) \text { is Borel}\}.$$

Show that $\mathcal E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, using the injectivity of $f.$